# How is analog current converted to USB?

Tags: usb

Im drawing a schematics for a procedure. We are using an anemometer which both outputs current proportional to wind speed. It also has USB output and software to read the speed for users who want to use this way. I can draw the current loops ect. in schematics but I dont know how the current is converted to USB and I also cannot find USB component in LTspice for drawings.

I dont have the detailed data sheet unfortunately. But I only need the "generic name" of the component which converts current readings to USB.

Do you have any idea? Here is the only data they provide:
http://www.fttech.co.uk/ufiles/file/EN_Acu-Test%20Analogue%20Datasheet%202A4204EN.pdf

Comment: Its called a microcontroller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [analog-to-digital converter (ADC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter) will convert analog signals into a quantized digital value. I can't say I have ever used the symbol in a schematic, but Wikipedia says to looks like this:

[image]

An ADC isn't the whole story with getting analog to USB though. You'd also need a device to collect the digital data and package it for transmission over the USB. That could be a few different things. I would use a microcontroller. The schematic symbol for that varies greatly, it's a descriptive symbol rather than a representative one, if that makes sense.

In your case the ADC and controller and inside the sensor device. If I were just doing a representation of it, I would show the sensor/adc/controller as a single abstracted component, which outputs both digital and analog signals. You may require more detail.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot find USB component in LTspice for drawings. I only need the "generic name" of the component which converts current readings to USB.

LTSpice will have no idea how to do this and logically that makes sense to me.

The USB output connects to your PC and communicates with the software on the PC. How your sensor decides to encode that information and how your PC software decodes that information is beyond the scope of what LTSpice is intended for.

This is not something that LTSpice or anyone needs to worry about simulating.

If you are using LTSpice to create a drawing (not use it as a simulation) then create any symbol you want and label it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "generic name" since this "device" usually includes at least some sort of ADC and microcontroller (ADC is possible integrated into the microcontroller) to transfer the (analog) readings into a protocol which can be understood by the USB host on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

### It's in a different world

LTspice is a tool to simulate a circuit on the level of basic electronic components, using information about their physical properties - e.g. of resistors and coils.

But an USB interface, containing a microprocessor, is something else entirely:
At the level LTspice is simulating, it consists of a huge count of basic components, on the order of milions.

It makes just no sense to try simulate it together with your example circuit. It's a different world: Reasoning about components of this complexity is on a different level of abstraction. Useful simulation of USB could be on the level of the stream transfer protocol - not even near hardware.

### USB is like icecream

A USB interface is so far of from what LTspice is working on that it does not even have, or need, the concept of "USB".
Just like it does not have, or need, the concepts "airline ticket refund" or "icecream".

So, if you're working on a USB connected icecream vending machine, draw two boxes, and write into them what they symbolize: "USB-ADC", and "icecream".